# How do i use the mongo query and traverse the mongo(JSON)document and fetch the element by key

Tags: jquery, arrays, mongodb

How do I use the Mongo query and  traverse into multiple array and fetch value of the key. Here is the my json

```
{
    "_id" : "t5ZcjQuysxcsHoDJg",
    "original" : {
            "name" : "images (1).jpg",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-03-18T11:48:33.124Z"),
            "size" : 10881,
            "type" : "image/jpeg"
    },
    "uploadedAt" : ISODate("2015-08-16T13:13:35.392Z"),
    "copies" : {
            "uploads" : {
                    "name" : "images (1).jpg",
                    "type" : "image/jpeg",
                    "size" : 10881,
                    "key" : "uploads-t5ZcjQuysxcsHoDJg-images (1).jpg",
                    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-08-16T13:13:35Z"),
                    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-08-16T13:13:35Z")
            }
    }
```

I want to fetch the value of size. Example I can fetch the value of uploadedAt as below

```
 db.cfs.uploads.filerecord.find({},{uploadedAt:1}).pretty()
```

like vise i have to get the value of size how the query should be ?

Answer (score 1):

The query can be whatever you want that will return a document. `{}`, for example. You can use a *projection* as the second parameter of the `find()` method, to limit the amount of data returned.

When you have a valid `doc` object, you can use `doc.original.size` to access the property you want.

In the mongo shell:

```
var cursor =  db.cfs.uploads.filerecord.find({}, { "original.size": 1})
var doc = cursor.next()
// { "_id" : "t5ZcjQuysxcsHoDJg", "original" : { "size" : 10881 } }
var size = doc.original.size
// 10881
```

Comment: Thank you i have tried as my answer below its works fine. previously i have missed colons

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and work fine .

```
 db.cfs.uploads.filerecord.find({},{'copies.uploads.size':1}).pretty().
```

Please dont forget to add colons. That what i was missed previously.